# Transfer a subset of properties to child component in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a stylized InputText component which I use in my forms. I don't want to repeat all the possible input properties in my props definition so I extended the React one.

```
import React, { useState, LegacyRef } from "react";
import Container, { ContainerProps } from "./Container";

export type InputTextProps = ContainerProps &
  React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & {
    inputRef?: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  };

const InputText: React.FC<InputTextProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container {...(props as ContainerProps)} focused={focused}>
      <input
        className="p-2 leading-normal rounded focus:outline-none border-box w-full"
        {...(props as React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>)}
        ref={props.inputRef}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default InputText;
```

But now I have that error in my Javascript console, which makes sense

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `inputRef` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `inputref` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Is there a clean way to achieve that simple Props inheritence in React or in Typescript ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's complaining about either `props as React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` (and maybe also `props as ContainerProps`). A pattern I like for this scenario is to deconstruct the props you want to propagate as `...rest`. For you this means:

```
const InputText: React.FC<InputTextProps> = ({
  inputRef,
  ...rest
}: InputTextProps) => {
  return (
    <Container {...(rest as ContainerProps)} focused={focused}>
      <input
        className="p-2 leading-normal rounded focus:outline-none border-box w-full"
        {...(rest as React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>)}
        ref={props.inputRef}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Also typecasting is generally a bad practice. Is there any particular reason why you require this? Overflow props are fine by TypeScript.

Comment: Nice solution ! I'll see if I can use it with two different parents.
I'm using typecasting to "filter" the props that are not part of the type. But that's not working at all !